# Google Chrome MIME type for .csv file?

Tags: csv, google-chrome, nginx, browser, mime-types

Does Google chrome support csv MIME type? I have the following entries in my mime.types (Nginx) file (these are only csv related entries):

```
types {
  text/csv                              csv;
  text/comma-separated-values           csv;
  text/anytext                          csv;
  application/csv                       csv;
  application/csv+xml                   csv;
```

}

Here is my nginx.conf file:

```
    user  nginx;
    worker_processes  1;

    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
    pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


    events {
      worker_connections  1024;
    }


    http {
      include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
      default_type  application/octet-stream;

      gzip_types text/plain text/xml text/css
                   text/comma-separated-values
                   text/javascript application/x-javascript
                   application/atom+xml;

      log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

      access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

      sendfile        off;
      #tcp_nopush     on;
      keepalive_timeout  65;
      #gzip  on;
      include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

But Chrome won't like it! No problem on Safari though!

Is there a Chrome specific csv support?

Thanks

Comment: Open the csv url & look at the network inspector in chrome, what content-type header is your server returning?

Comment: application/json; charset=utf-8

Comment: @AlexK. I answered the question, thought I'd let you know. Thanks anyways

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue by adding:

```
add_header  Content-Type    text/csv;
```

to the nginx webapp.conf file where I define my specific location:

```
location /ingressfile {
    access_log /var/log/nginx/ingressfile.log main;

    set   $module   company.api;
    set   $app      app;
    uwsgi_pass      restapi;
    uwsgi_intercept_errors on;
    # add support for csv files
    add_header  Content-Type    text/csv;

    # Use this I'm-a-teapot code to redirect to static file
    error_page 418 = @ingressfile;
}
```

Hopefully this helps people with the same kind of issues!